# Verify that the following statements about a mapping $f:X\rightarrow Y$ are equivalent.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Verify that the following statements about a mapping $f:X\rightarrow Y$ are equivalent:

a) $f$ is injective.

b) $f^{-1}(f(A)) = A$ for every $A\subset X$.

c) $f(A\cap B) = f(A)\cap f(B)$ for any two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$.

d) $f(A)\cap f(B) = \varnothing \Leftrightarrow A\cap B = \varnothing$

e) $f(A\backslash B) = f(A)\backslash f(B)$ whenever $X\supset A\supset B$.

I have been able to prove the implications $a\Rightarrow b$ and $c\Rightarrow d$. It still remains to prove $b\Rightarrow c$, $d\Rightarrow e$ and $e\Rightarrow a$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that $f[A \cap B]\subseteq f[A] \cap f[B]$ always.

Now, if $b)$ holds and $y \in f[A] \cap f[B]$ there is a unique (!) $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$ (say $x \neq x'$ would both work, then $A=\{x\}$ obeys $\{x,x'\} \subseteq f^{-1}[f[A]]\neq A$, contradicting $b)$) This unique $x$ must thus be in $A \cap B$, or $y$ would not have been in $f[A] \cap f[B]$..So we have equality in $c)$

$d) \implies e)$: $f[A]\setminus f[B] \subseteq f[A \setminus B]$ always, so take $y \in f[A \setminus B]$. Again there is a unique $x \in A \setminus B$ with $f(x)=y$ (otherwise $x \neq x'$ both work and $A=\{x\}, B=\{x'\}$ could contradict $d)$). So $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$, so $y \notin f[B]$ (its unique preimage is not in $B$) and the other inclusion has been shown.

$e) \implies a)$: Suppose $f(x)=f(x')=y$ for some pair $x \neq x'$. This contradicts $e)$: $A=\{x,x'\}, B = \{x\}$, $A \setminus B=\{x'\}$ and $f[A]=f[B]=\{y\}$ and so $$f[A]\setminus f[B]=\emptyset \neq \{y\}=f[A \setminus B]$$ Hence $f$ is injective.

Comment: In the first place, thank you very much for the contribution. Still, I would like to know if there is a more direct approach based on the properties of $f^{-1}$, which I know that it does not necessarily represent a function.

Comment: @eagertolearn you can also change the order in which you prove the implications

Comment: I am going to keep trying for a while.

Comment: @eagertolearn $f^{-1}[f[A]]=A$ clearly implies 1-1 directly: if $f(x)=f(x')$ define $A = \{x\}$ and then  $\{x,x'\} \subseteq f^{-1}[f[A]]=A=\{x\}$  so $x'=x$. It's even enough to demand $b)$ for singletons only...